# Flow not updating new record field values although debug says assignment fields have values

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a simple flow that gets the leads and updates them with borrower and applicant values from Applicant object.

As per debug logs, the Flow value assignment is successful and values are populated. UpdateLeads action also show "1" one as value which means there's one record being updated.

But checking the record on Dev Console, the 2 fields mentioned still were blank. Any idea why ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the flow debugger?  It gives you a lot of detail on each step.  Flow looks fine overall.

Comment: its a record triggered flow and debug feature doesn't work. i uploaded the message on the debug

Comment: i found i had to create an entirely new list, and use that on the update records. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I was using the list of records from the GetRecords to update. When I tried to create my whole new entire list where I construct each new record along with the record Id and assigned fields, and use that on the UpdateRecords, it worked now.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that was fixed.  I did have to do that in the past.  It's definitely safer and has no negatives.